# Solidity error message on compilation (DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. using Address for address;)

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, crowdsale

I'm trying to compile a code for a crowdsale contract (Timed and with allowance) from openzeppelin library that is based on a deployed token. However during compilation on remix i get a syntax error as below

> browser/TestCrowdsale.sol:330:11: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
>
> using Address for address;
>
> ^-----^

I tried with latest compiler 0.6.1 and with 0.5.0 still same result.

can someone advise whats the issue with the code

Also where should i pass the address of the deployed contract to the crowdsale contract?

Code: https://paste2.org/ULhxpLAv

Comment: Can you provide the code in a more usable format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into it quickly I noticed you did not import the [library Address](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Address.sol) and this is probably why your `using Address as address` doesn't work. Hope this helps.